# File delete in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, uri, permission-denied

I have written a piece of code that creates a new file, downloads the contents in the image URL into the file and uploads it to carrierwave using 'mount_base64_uploader'. After this operation, I have to delete the file. My code looks like below

```
open(self.name + '.png', 'wb') do |readfile|
  unless self.image_url.nil?
    if self.image_url =~ URI::regexp
      readfile << open(self.image_url).read
    else 
      readfile << open(DEFAULT_IMAGE).read
    end  
  else
    readfile << open(DEFAULT_IMAGE).read
  end
  self.file = readfile
  File.delete(readfile)
end
```

where DEFAULT_IMAGE is a default image URL that serves as a placeholder. However, I get an error when it tries to delete the file as

> Permission denied @ unlink_internal

Could anyone guide me here if I need to change the code or add permissions explicitly.

Comment: It is possible that your OS refuses to delete open files. Try deleting the file after the block closes (which automatically closes the file).

Comment: @Vishnukk Feel free to accept/upvote if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this can be done as -

Assuming there is an `image` attribute mounted for CarrierWave uploader

```
def store_url_image(img_url: DEFAULT_IMAGE)
  self.remote_image_url = img_url
  self.save
end

object.store_url_image(img_url: "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1407/m31_bers_960.jpg")
```

[#Reference Upload remote image url](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Upload-remote-image-urls-to-your-seedfile)

Comment: The motive is to hide the original URLs from the end-users and hence I thought of uploading as a file rather than the URL directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a  permissions issue on your /usr/local/lib/ directory & you could grant the current user the necessary permissions and then try re-executing the brew cleanup command. Something along the lines of:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib

brew cleanup
```